# How to construct a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I am a very new programmer, it is part of my degree requirements and I am having a hard time with it. I am working on basically a three part GUI and I am wondering how I would create a JTextArea that will display each item that is entered.

Answer (score 4):

Start by taking a look at [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), this will give you a basic grounding in how to use Swing.

Take a closer look at [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) for specific details about how to use `JTextArea`